# Вопрос по указателям

Tags: c++, указатели

**Еслть вот такой вод код:**

```
#include <iostream>


void toZero(int *mass, int length) {
    int res[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        res[i] = 0;
    }
    mass = res;
}


int main() {
    int mass[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    toZero(mass, 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        std::cout << *(mass + i) << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Результат выполнения:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

**Вопрос:**
В функции `toZero` первый элемент массив mass после строки `mass = res;`  должен(?) ссылаться на первый элемент массива res. Но этого не происходит, почему ?

Comment: Как понимаете, что не происходит? В отладчике смотрите?

Comment: Потому что при вызове `toZero` создаётся локальная переменная `mass`, в которую помещается ***значение*** `mass` из функции `main` (то есть, адрес первого элемента массива). После выхода из функции `toZero` эта локальная переменная уничтожается, а `mass` из `main` при этом, очевидно, не изменяется.

Comment: `mass` это локальная переменная, вы её меняете `mass = res`, но дальше нигде не используете

Comment: Спасибо! Я понял, но как правильно сделать ?

Comment: 1) Вынести объявление `res` из функции, поскольку она тоже является локальной переменной. 2) Передавать в `toZero` не `int*`, а `int**`.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать функцию, обнуляющую массив?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
void toZero(int *mass, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        mass[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

А еще вместо того чтобы писать toZero можно воспользоваться стандартным алгоритмом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const int size = 7;
    int mass[size ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    std::fill_n(mass, size, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        std::cout << *(mass + i) << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

По просьбам зрителей:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    const int size = 7;
    int mass[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    std::fill_n(mass, size, 0);
    std::copy(mass, mass + size, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А fill_n и memset это одно и тоже?

Comment: @pavel, нет. Если у вас будет массив объектов у которые не являются POD типами, то memset создаст вам трудноуловимый баг, который еще и появляться  будет не на каждом компиляторе.

Comment: @pavel, хотя наверняка в некоторых(или может во многих) реализациях стандартной библиотеки `std::fill_n` для POD типов выполнен именно при помощи memset, а для остальных при помощи цикла и оператора копирующего присваивания

Comment: К слову `std::fill_n` не обнулит массивы объектов POD, если объекты не поддерживают соответствующий оператор (`=`). `memset` в этом плане идет напролом ) (с соответствующими проблемами, разумеется)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, а вы можете привести пример POD типа, для которого компилятор не сгенерирует operator= ?

Comment: Судя по вопросу, ТС в самом начале изучения языка, в таком случае самый подходящий - первый вариант.

Comment: Оператор то он сгенерирует, но не с аргументом типа int же